# UBUNTU 18.04 Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out

Tags: mount, samba

I was able to connect to my sambashare once. Once I disconnected and tried to reconnect via GUI (smb://ip_address/share) I receive an error message saying "Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out." I searched the issue for a while and only found older solutions that didn't fix my problem.